# Maven, replace token in files for debug and compilation

Tags: maven, replace, token

First of all, im using maven.
My src code has properties that point to different resources, those resources have different paths depending on the developer´s machine. So i need a way assign tokens to those properties in the source code so when you debug it or package it those properties are assigned to for example environment variables, that way each developer can have the resources saved in different places.
These properties arent in .java files, the only way to change them is parsing the file to find the token.

Thanks for your help, i tried to use maven-replace-plugin but it replaces in the source files breaking it for everyone else.

Comment: What kind of "resources" are you talking about? Why don't you use environment variables for that?

Comment: Please elaborate what exactly resources you are talking about as JF Meier wrote...